# concurrent.future to execute two different functions with different parameters

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I am trying to make concurrent.future to execute two different functions with different parameters. However, it was not successful. The desired functions are listed as follows:

```
def func1(para1, para2):
    time.sleep(para1)
    print(para2)
def func2(para1, para2, para3):
    time.speep(para2)
    print(para2+para3)
```

Lots of online tutorials demonstrate same function used multiple times with only 1 parameter per function. I got no luck to run 2 different functions with different parameters to run using concurrent.future. Any idea?

Fixed code according to James' reply:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait
import time
start_time = time.time()

def fn_a(s,v):
    t_sleep = s
    print("function a: Wait {} seconds".format(t_sleep))
    time.sleep(t_sleep)
    ret = v * 5 # return different results
    print(f"function a: return {ret}")
    return ret

def fn_b(s,v):
    t_sleep = s
    print("function b: Wait {} seconds".format(t_sleep))
    time.sleep(t_sleep)
    ret = v * 10 # return different results
    print(f"function b: return {ret}")
    return ret

def fn_c(s,v):
    t_sleep = s
    print("function c: Wait {} seconds".format(t_sleep))
    time.sleep(t_sleep)
    ret = v * 20 # return different results
    print(f"function c: return {ret}")
    return ret

output = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = []
    futures.append(executor.submit(fn_a, 5, 1.1))
    futures.append(executor.submit(fn_b, 4, 2.2))
    futures.append(executor.submit(fn_c, 8, 3.3))
    complete_futures, incomplete_futures = wait(futures)
    for f in complete_futures:
        output.append(f.result())
        print(str(f.result()))

elapsed = (time.time() - start_time)
print(f"Total time of execution {round(elapsed, 4)} second(s)")
print("Output is:",output)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can submit the functions in sequence to your executor with your desired parameters.

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def func1(para1, para2):
    time.sleep(para1)
    print(para2)

def func2(para1, para2, para3):
    time.sleep(para1)
    print(para2+para3)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as ex:
    futures = []
    futures.append(ex.submit(func1, 3, 'hello'))
    futures.append(ex.submit(func2, 2, 'world', 'blah'))

# prints:
worldblah
hello
```